# How to remove left margin in the column with image (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a listing and each row will consist of 3 columns. The first column contains the image. But the problem is that there is a white space on the left side of the image. How can be it removed?

```
 <div class="row jobs-card  align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <image class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/13/10/logo-1933884_960_720.png"/>
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-8 float-left">
     <h2> Heading for listing. </h2>
     <h5> company name ! category </h5>
     <p> specialist for manufacturing company </p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 float-right ">
     <p class="mx-auto">
       10m ago </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

**css**

```
.jobs-card {
   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
margin-top:30px;  

}
```

How can that white space be removed on the left side of the image?

Comment: The HTML tag is `img` not `image`

Comment: The answer mentioned there is not working it removes left margin but adds margin from both sides out of the row.

Comment: Make sure you read the entire answer. You just need to use `px-0` on the `col-md-2` with the image.